# Test capacity of HAProxy Load Balance solution on Amazon EC2 Micro-instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, load-balancing, haproxy

Currently we have a domain name registered with an ISP that points to an Amazon EC2 instance with an Elastic IP.  This instance is running IIS hosting a simple ASP.NET site that URL forwards visitors to two external sites via round-robin.

This EC2 instance is a Windows Large and is costing us about $350ish dollars a month.  I think this is a really bad solution URL forwarding/Load balancing solution.

I think what we need is a micro EC2 instance running HAProxy that will do our URL redirects and load balancing.  Given that the number of users using the service is less than 5000 and the number of daily connections will be less than 10,000.

However I do not want to create bottleneck by choosing too small an instance type.

How can I test the HAProxy setup to determine the number of connections it can comfortably manage?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should perform stress testing using one of load testing tools. I recommend using `siege`, `JMeter` or `Tsung`.
`siege` is the simplest one and it should suit your needs since you don't need complex testing scenarios.

Comment: Thanks siege looks interesting I think I will give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

Can I ask, have you ever performed any benchmarks on your Large Instance without any of the IIS redirecting/round robin in front of it?  You may not even have a load issue, or not where you [think it is](http://www.faqs.org/docs/artu/ch12s02.html).

Secondly, if you do need a load balancer, I'd recommend looking into Amazon's [Elastic Load Balancing](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/) service to take away some of the guesswork of right-sizing your instance for HAProxy.

Comment: The question states the sites are external so cannot use ELB from AWS.  Also the driver behind the change is cost, not a load bottleneck.

Comment: You're right: should've clarified that first.